# What's the best way to store regex strings in Haskell?

Tags: regex, haskell, coding-style

I have a function `remove` which takes a regex as a string and another string. It removes anything that matches the regex from the second string and returns it.

At the moment, I'm calling the `remove` function with literal regex strings, for example:

```
remove "(my|a)?string" "Test string" -- returns "Test "
```

This program is going to grow and there will be lots of regex's to call, and each one may be used several times throughout the program.  Should I be storing them like this:

```
myregex = "(my|a)?string"
```

or should I be making a data type or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use partial application as in:

```
remove regex str = <generic code to remove the regex expression from string>
```

For each specific type of regex you want to apply, you can write a function like:

```
removeName = remove "<name_regex>"
```

and so on. Then you can use those functions like

```
removeName "myname"
```

Answer (score 4):

If performance is a concern, any regexen you intend to use multiple times should be compiled once and stored in compiled form. See also the documentation for [makeRegex](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#v%3amakeRegex).